# System Preferences quits unexpectedly due to MySQL plug-in

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x

I've installed [MySQL Preference Pane](http://creativeeyes.at/tools/mysqlpp.php) on my MacBook to start/stop MySQL from my System Preferences and it works ok, except that once in a while System Preferences just quits and shows this message:

```
The application System Preferences quit unexpectedly.
The problem may have been caused by the MySQL plug-in.
```

MySQL remains up and running and I can just restart System Preferences without any trouble, but what causes this crash and how can I fix it?

Here's what I see on my OS X Console:

```
10:45:55 pearl-macbook ReportCrash[6365]: Formulating crash report for
process System Preferences[3671]

10:45:56 pearl-macbook ReportCrash[6365]: Saved crashreport to 
/Users/pearl/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/System Preferences_2013-04-11-104552_pearl-macbook.crash 
using uid: 501 gid: 20, euid: 501 egid: 20

10:45:56 pearl-macbook com.apple.launchd[83]([0x0-0x5e05e].com.apple.systempreferences[3671]): 
Stray process with PGID equal to this dead job: PID 6364 PPID 1 System Preferenc

10:45:56 pearl-macbook com.apple.launchd[83]([0x0-0x5e05e].com.apple.systempreferences[3671]): 
Exited abnormally: Bus error
```